# What is the method i have to use to find correlation between multiple variables

Tags: r, correlation

I know how to find a correlation between 2 variables. How am i supposed to find correlations between multiple variables and how do i plot a graph for it?

Comment: Questions solely about how software works are
[off-topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here, but
you may have a real statistical question buried here. 
You may want to edit your question to clarify the underlying 
statistical issue. You may find that when you understand 
the statistical concepts involved, the software-specific elements are 
self-evident or at least easy to get from the documentation.

Comment: plot a graph for what, exactly?

Comment: a graph which represents the relation between multiple variables like the one you get in r programming

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210528/statistic-test-for-confirming-pattern-of-sales-every-month Similar question(waiting for answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In R you can do something like:

## Correlation

res <- cor(df)

## Visualization

library(corrplot)
corrplot(res, type = "upper", order = "hclust", 
         tl.col = "black", tl.srt = 45)

Answer (score 0):

Correlation is a measure that applies to pairs of variables.  There is no "correlation among three variables".  If you mean all the pairs of variables, then the answer will be software dependent.  There are different ways to graph multiple pairs of correlations.  One way is a scatterplot matrix.